Laravel unique rule on composite index excluding current entity
I have the following table
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CountryCode` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `StudioID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `StudioID` (`CountryCode`) USING BTREE
)

This table has a unique composite index on CountryCode and StudioID
UNIQUE INDEX `CountryCode` (`StudioID`) USING BTREE

I have patch endpoint that should allows updating on the same entity(exclude current id basically).
I can't seem to get it working.
I've tried so far
Rule::unique('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where('CountryCode', $this->input('StudioID'))
        ->where('StudioID', $this->input('CountryCode'));
})->ignore($this->route('country')->CountryCode)
->ignore($this->route('country')->StudioID),

or
Rule::unique('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where('CountryCode', $this->input('StudioID'))
        ->where('StudioID', $this->input('CountryCode'));
})->ignore($this->route('country')->id),

or
Rule::unique('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where('CountryCode', $this->input('StudioID'))
        ->where('StudioID', $this->input('CountryCode'))

        ->where('CountryCode', '!=', $this->input('StudioID'))
        ->where('CountryCode', '!=', $this->input('CountryCode'))
;
}),


Rule::unique('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query
                    ->where('CountryCode', $this->input('StudioID'))
                    ->where('StudioID', $this->input('CountryCode'));
            })->ignore($this->route('country'))

Only specify $this->route('country') within the ignore method. extracting id might throw an exception when there is no model instance.
